# Linearizing a load cell

Tags: load-cell, calibration

As I understand it most load cells (all?) are only approximately linear. To improve the linearity would a 3 point calibration be sufficient? For example, at no load, half load and maximum load. If so, what kind of linearizing equation or technique is used?

Comment: It depends on: What accuracy do you need? How accurate (linear) the load cell is by itself (maybe it is already accurate enough for your application?). Maybe a one-point calibration is all that's needed? You can go all the way with fancy algorithms (as suggested below) but I suggest that you first ask yourself: what do I need?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie We can already get a resolution of 1:10^5, so to answer your question is "As accurate as the technology permits".

Comment: Realize that resolution and accuracy aren't the same thing. A setup with a high resolution allows me to see small changes but the actual value I measure doesn't have to be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If low order 'harmonic distortion' is your main problem, then a low order curve fit is going to give you a big improvement. Two points can only define a straight line, but three will give you a curve, a parabola or circular arc at your choice, but parabola is easier to code, and they're barely distinguishable for small curvature.

It will not improve on any errors generated by changes of temperature, or hysteresis, both of which can be corrected for in other ways. It won't correct for resetability, which is uncorrectable, and looking at the mechanics in kitchen scales I've dismantled, probably quite a significant source of error in cheap load cells.

There's little point to trying to get more accuracy from any curve fitting than the errors of the second paragraph limit you to.

Answer (score 2):

It's bound to be an improvement, maybe 2:1. You'd really have to run the numbers to compare error sources and see if improving the linearity yields substantial improvement.

Some ASICs use a 10 breakpoint LUT (adjustable breakpoint position, not fixed).

For similar, almost linear, sensors I've used polynomial fits in extremely resource-constrained applications, though the condition number is poor on such methods so you need a lot of extra bits in the calculations, which slows things.

In 2020, if you have reasonable computing resources available, consider a cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: I will be using a chip that can do 90 MFLOPS so I am not resource limited there. One completed measurement every 10 seconds is the spec to which I am working. So lots of stats and filtering the crap out of it etc.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure that single-precision floats are inadequate for your application, if a polynomial fit is used.

Comment: It does doubles as well - Cortex M4F

Comment: Good. Last I looked, only a few of the Cortex M4/M7 have double-precision FPUs, though they'll all do it with software, of course.